# LLDB Python API SBAddress constructor error

Tags: lldb

I'm trying to create an SB Value from an address value that I have, and I'm running into an issue with the SBAddress constructor. When I do this:

```
target = lldb.debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
pointer = target.FindFirstType('node_t').GetPointerType()
root = target.CreateValueFromAddress('root', lldb.SBAddress(0x100004058, target), pointer)
```

And then I run

```
root.GetValue()
```

I get something like 0x0000000100004041

Is there something wrong that I'm doing here with the constructor of the SBAddress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful about what's pointing to what to get this right.  Is 0x100004058 the VALUE of the pointer you want to make a type from, or the LOCATION of that pointer?  I suspect it is the former...

The memory at the address which is the value of the pointer holds an object of type "node_t".  So when you want to make an SBValue out of that memory, the type you want is "node_t" not "node_t *".

However, if 0x100004058 were the location of the pointer, then making a value as a pointer to node_t at that address would be correct.

So, for instance, stopped here:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x4ae2e3, function: take_void , stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f33 pointers`take_void at pointers.c:12
   9    void
   10   take_void(void *input)
   11   {
-> 12     printf("Got pointer: %p.\n", input);
   13   }
   14       
   15   int
```

called from:

```
   15   int
   16   main()
   17   {
   18     struct Foo my_foo = {111, 222};
   19     take_void (&my_foo);
   20     return 0;
   21   }
```

then:

```
(lldb) fr v -L
0x00007fff5fbff658: (void *) input = 0x00007fff5fbff670
```

The first address is the location of input, so:

```
(lldb) script
>>> ptr_type = lldb.target.FindFirstType('Foo').GetPointerType()
>>> root = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("root", lldb.SBAddress(0x00007fff5fbff658, lldb.target), ptr_type)
>>> root.GetValue()
    '0x00007fff5fbff670'
```

Which is what you expect.  And:

```
>>> root = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("root", lldb.SBAddress(0x00007fff5fbff670, lldb.target), type)
>>> root.GetValue()
```

That's right because structures don't have values.  And:

```
>>> root.GetChildAtIndex(0).GetValue()
'111'
>>> root.GetChildAtIndex(1).GetValue()
'222'
```

Those were the values that I put in the fields, so that is right.  And:

```
>>> root = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("root", lldb.SBAddress(0x00007fff5fbff670, lldb.target), ptr_type)
>>> root.GetValue()
'0x000000de0000006f'
```

(which is probably the error you were making) makes sense too, because 0xde is 222 and 0x6f is 111 and I'm on a little-endian system...

Comment: Let's say I have a global variable 'root', which I can get by running root = lldb.target.FindFirstGlobalVariable('root'), and then I run root.GetValue() which gives me a value 0x100004058 and root.GetType() gives me 'node_t*'. Now I want to create the same exact variable by using lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress(), with the same result from root.GetType(). This is where I am running into problems.

Comment: The value of a pointer is the memory pointed at by the pointer.  The object residing in that memory is of the pointee type of that pointer.  So in your case, when you go to create a value from the address you get back from GetValue on your "root" object, the type you want to use is "node_t" not "node_t *".

Comment: Right. I get this and thanks.

Just wanted to ask one question. In the above example you gave, root.GetValue() returns None because a structure doesn't have a 'value'. But actually it contains two children who have legitimate values. Suppose I passed in an invalid address where there is junk, root.GetValue() still return None and it still says there are two children with the root.GetNumChildren() function. But of course, the two children return None when GetValue() is called. Is there an easier way to find if the root variable actually contains junk?

Comment: The value is usually bad because it is unreadable.  So when you fetched the value of root in CreateValueFromAddress, there would have been a memory read error.  SBValue::GetError() will get you that error (you should check this every time you make and SBValue.  The SBError will tell you whether the creation succeeded or failed, and has a string with more details.

Comment: Okay, here too I see the same problem in that running root.GetChildMemberWithName('data').GetChildAtIndex(0).GetError() returns the fact that there is a read memory error, but running root.GetError() just returns 'success'. I specifically want to know if the member fields inside the root Variable are junk.

Comment: I realize it is possible to iterate through the children like for child in root: and so on, but I wondered if there is a way to directly check if the children inside are junk.

Comment: Define "junk".  If the structure is in readable memory, then all the fields have fetchable values, so by some definition they are all good.  If one of the fields is an integer, it can't have "junk" values, since all bit patterns map to valid integers.  If a field is a pointer, then the pointer value might not be initialized, in which case it could point to NULL, to a unreadable memory, or even to unrelated but readable memory.  When you try to fetch the pointee, lldb could tell you if that is unreadable, but that's not the only kind of junk...

Comment: Maybe this is what I really wanted, but if I have an address value, say 0x100003430, and I wanted to create an SBValue object as a pointer to point to that memory address, is it possible to do that with CreateValueFromAddress? Or would I have to do it with SetValueFromCString() to be that memory address? SetValueFromCString() returns False when I try to do this after initializing a variable with an empty lldb.SBValue() constructor

Comment: If you have a structure laid out starting at 0x100003430, you can use CreateValueFromAddress with that address, and the structure type, then call SBValue.AddressOf() to get an SBValue which points to the structure value.  That should work though I've never done that.

Comment: @JimIngham what a great answer.  Thank you, as always.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `SBValue`'s own `CreateValueFromAddress` method. It's not documented too well, but I've figured out the parameters and they are simpler than that of target's. Use it like so (no need for special address functions, just plain + operator):

```py
offset_in_bytes = base_address + some_offset
some_other_sbvalue.CreateValueFromAddress("name-of-new-value", offset_in_bytes, value_type)
```